# Best way to Query Microsoft AD with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory

Two part question:

1. What is the "best" way to query Microsoft AD with Python 3.x? With "best" defined as multi-OS support and use of core Python libraries preferable.
2. Examples of querying AD structure for members of a specific AD group would be extremely appreciated.

I've looked at a few different libraries, but had issues loading them under OS X, Python 3, etc. Hoping someone's already looked at this issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try the ldap3 package from Pypi at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ldap3. It strictly follows the latest rfc for LDAP and is a pure Python implementation so can be used on different platforms, either with Python 2 (2.6 or 2.7) or Python 3

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the ldap3 library.

Comment: ldap3 doesn't seem to handle SRV records? Which likely means it can't handle domain controller failovers, for example.

Comment: Discovering of ldap server via SVR is not part of the LDAP standard (as specified in RFC4510 and related RFCs). It is part of the Active Directory implementation. You can use a python library for query DNS and then in ldap3 you can create a server pool with those servers.